# USB keyboard doesn't work with Debian installer

Tags: debian, system-installation, usb, keyboard

I have a wired USB keyboard. I've written the latest netinstall Wheezy image on my USB pendrive (using `dd`). It boots but the installer doesn't recognize the keyboard! (The same pendrive works on my laptop) I am guessing my [motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2539#ov) is no longer supported by this installer. How can I make the keyboard work with the installer?

Comment: did you check your BIOS settings? legacy USB should be also enabled.

Comment: @bersch it's always enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I can not reply to damn's comment, but adding iommu=soft solved it for me too. I tried with the noapic nolapic options and wih the IOMMU fom the bios and all failed.

Simply follow the same steps as described by slm but add iommu=soft on the start command line instead of noapic nolapic.

Answer (score 1):

When booting try providing this command at the boot prompt:

```
boot: linux noapic nolapic
```

Also you might want to try this:

```
boot: install expertgui
```

**NOTE:** Given you do not have access to the keyboard during installation providing these might be problematic. You can try adding `noapic` and `nolapic` to the end of the `linux` boot command that's contained in a config file on your USB.

#### Accessing the "Boot Menu"

If you're able to finagle any keyboard functionality during installation you can access the `:boot` menu by using the <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> keys and highlighting an option, say Graphical Install, within the "Boot Menu" (**#1** in diagram). Then hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> (**#2**) to access the kernel boot command. Here you can append and/or change the options passed to the Linux kernel (**#3**) prior to booting it.

[image: ss #1]

#### Accessing the boot menu's config files

If you go poking around on your USB's installation media that you're using you'll notice the following directory structure.

```
$ ls -l
total 570
-r--r--r--. 1 saml saml     25 Oct 13 16:59 autorun.inf
lr-xr-xr-x. 1 saml saml      1 Oct 13 16:58 debian -> .
dr-xr-xr-x. 1 saml saml   2048 Oct 13 16:58 dists
dr-xr-xr-x. 1 saml saml   2048 Oct 13 16:57 firmware
-r--r--r--. 1 saml saml 159629 Oct 13 16:59 g2ldr
-r--r--r--. 1 saml saml   8192 Oct 13 16:59 g2ldr.mbr
dr-xr-xr-x. 1 saml saml   2048 Oct 13 16:59 install
dr-xr-xr-x. 1 saml saml   2048 Oct 13 16:58 isolinux
dr-xr-xr-x. 1 saml saml   2048 Oct 13 16:58 live
-r--r--r--. 1 saml saml  33392 Oct 13 16:59 md5sum.txt
dr-xr-xr-x. 1 saml saml   2048 Oct 13 16:58 pool
-r--r--r--. 1 saml saml 366350 Oct 13 16:59 setup.exe
dr-xr-xr-x. 1 saml saml   2048 Oct 13 16:59 tools
-r--r--r--. 1 saml saml    228 Oct 13 16:59 win32-loader.ini
```

Take notice of the directory, `isolinux`, which contains the "Boot Menu" contents. Specifically look at the `.cfg` files.

```
$ more install.cfg 
label install
    menu label ^Install
    linux /install/vmlinuz
    initrd /install/initrd.gz
    append vga=788  -- quiet

label installgui
    menu label ^Graphical install
    linux /install/gtk/vmlinuz
    initrd /install/gtk/initrd.gz
    append video=vesa:ywrap,mtrr vga=788  -- quiet
```

Add these arguments to the end of the `append` line, `noapic nolapic`.

```
    append vga=788  -- quiet noapic nolapic
```

#### References

- [DebianInstaller FAQ](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/FAQ#Q:_When_I_run_the_DebianInstaller.2C_my_keyboard_doesn.27t_work.21)

Comment: How do I bring up the boot prompt?

Comment: I believe it's under the "Advanced Options" http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.installation-steps.html

Comment: that's out of the question (keyboard doesn't work on that menu). i'd better try adding `noapic` and `nolapic` to the GRUB config file. but: how is editing GRUB on my hdd affects the installer which boots from USB? i mean GRUB isn't even used when I boot from USB.

Comment: @Infestor - I've not tried it directly but looking at the docs you should be able to get at te `:boot` prompt during installation: https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch05s01.html.en. See section 5.1.5.

Comment: @Infestor - see my updates that show how to modify the USB media to include the boot options.

Answer (score 1):

Solved for me by changing IOMMU in BIOS

There was no need for me to append the install.cfg.  I went into my BIOS and enabled IOMMU (in newer BIOS this may be called  Intel Virtualization Technology or Intel VT - Check your chipset, name varies).

My specific issue was installing crunchbang (64) and my wireless k350 keyboard and mouse was not working with the Unity Receiver during install (it booted the installer fine, but as soon as you click install the mouse/keyboard went off).  Saved me a trip to Walmart for a cheap keyboard which probably wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

People seem to hint at the IOMMU, sometimes suggesting kernel command line arguments. I second that, apparently the IOMMU has a say. On an ASUS motherboard with a ThreadRipper, I haven't found an option in the BIOS to enable/disable the IOMMU, but there was an option to enable SR-IOV, which is close, and was disabled by default. So I tried enabling it et voila... USB kb+mouse working. In the installer of Debian 12 with stock kernel 6.1.x. No extra kernel cmdline spells were necessary, for the installer or for the installed system.

Answer (score -1):

- Press <kbd>e</kbd> in GRUB/BootMenu to edit the boot command.
- Append `iommu=soft` to the line containing `linux`.
- Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

Also works for **Devuan**.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  How/where did you append this?