# Keyboard not working during Debian Install on LG Ultra laptop

Tags: keyboard, debian-installer

During install of an LG ultra laptop ( 17U70P ), the mouse work correctly, but the keyboard stop reacting after booting into "Graphical Install".

I was looking in the bios configuration, and found not specific option that could enable or restore this situation.

The keyboard is required to connect to the wifi (I have an additional USB with the firmware). I have no external keyboard to test.

**How to get the laptop keyboard working during install?**

Related question, which did not solved my case:

[USB keyboard doesn't work with Debian installer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116234/usb-keyboard-doesnt-work-with-debian-installer)

```
linux /install.amd/vmlinuz vga=788 --- quiet noapic nolapic

or

linux /install.amd/vmlinuz vga=788 --- quite iommu=soft
```

Did not worked, the first freeze, while the second keeps the keyboard not working.

Comment: Did you try to boot some Debian based live CD/USB e.g. Debian live CD, Kali, CAINE, etc. ? Full installation can tell you more about the HW and necessary modules.

Comment: No, I did not. I have to say that I am helping remotely to install Debian through some phone skype session, so this does not make easier to test. However, I will try on my next session.

Comment: After full install, keyboard and touchpad are still not working. External USB mouse and keyboard works properly, but this is not a solution for a laptop.

Comment: Any suggestion how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: For the record, I have the same issue with the same LG 17U70P, using Archlinux. The most frustrating thing is that the keyboard works perfectly in GRUB (I can select the desired kernel even edit the kernel parameters directly in laptop keyboard) but once linux boots, the laptop keyboard stops working. I've been digging in some threads pointing to SW_TABLET_MODE but in the end concluded that something is wrong specifically with the keyboard, seems that happened in the past with LG laptops as pointed here: https://groups.google.com/g/linux.kernel/c/0NdfVkltWGs/m/qHzrIMR6vToJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally! I found the problem and I've been using the laptop keyboard without any issue under Linux.

This laptop has the same problem [as described in this thread](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216158) in kernel.org, seems like the kernel is not properly handling the parameters of an IRQ. Following the ideas of the submitted patches in that thread I created this patch, I already tried it and works all right:

```
--- a/linux-6.1.8/drivers/acpi/resource.c   2023-01-24 07:24:44.000000000 +0100
+++ b/linux-6.1.8/drivers/acpi/resource.c   2023-01-27 20:47:52.241298057 +0100
@@ -471,6 +471,18 @@ static const struct dmi_system_id schenk
    { }
 };
 
+static const struct dmi_system_id lg_laptop[] = {
+   {
+       .ident = "LG Electronics 17U70P",
+       .matches = {
+           DMI_MATCH(DMI_SYS_VENDOR, "LG Electronics"),
+           DMI_MATCH(DMI_BOARD_NAME, "17U70P"),
+       },
+   },
+   { }
+};
+
+
 struct irq_override_cmp {
    const struct dmi_system_id *system;
    unsigned char irq;
@@ -486,6 +498,7 @@ static const struct irq_override_cmp ove
    { lenovo_laptop, 6, ACPI_LEVEL_SENSITIVE, ACPI_ACTIVE_LOW, 0, true },
    { lenovo_laptop, 10, ACPI_LEVEL_SENSITIVE, ACPI_ACTIVE_LOW, 0, true },
    { schenker_gm_rg, 1, ACPI_EDGE_SENSITIVE, ACPI_ACTIVE_LOW, 1, true },
+   { lg_laptop, 1, ACPI_LEVEL_SENSITIVE, ACPI_ACTIVE_LOW, 0, false },
 };
 
 static bool acpi_dev_irq_override(u32 gsi, u8 triggering, u8 polarity,
```

PS. Keyboard backlit is not working yet, I'm still looking into that

Update 2/27/23: Yesterday managed to turn on the backlit! Unless I receive some help I guess is gonna take a little bit to properly integrate in the current LG Gram WMI driver, so if in the meantime anybody is interested please ask me the patch.

Update 2/28/23: [I filled this bug in kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216983) for this specific laptop model, look here for additional patches/notes.

Comment: That's a good niews, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The short Answer:
The keyboard is currently not supported in any of the Linux Distro's I tried.

The Long Answer:
I have the same Laptop and I can confirm that I have had ZERO luck installing ANY Linux Distro's (I have tried most of them) that will actually recognize the keyboard! Any of the solutions out there that I could find, did not work. Those solutions ranged from Grub stuff, boot parameters, additional package installs, terminal hacks and kernel patches. At this point this is an unsolved issue.

Not sure what kind of Keyboard they put into this Laptop but its a shame that because of it this Laptop looses its Linux value. Granted you can always attach an external USB keyboard or a BT keyboard but that takes away from the portable laptop idea.

I may add, the only keys that were working, are three of the extra function keys: Display Brightness FN-F2 & FN-F3 and Airplane mode FN-F6 !
Everything else about this laptop is supported in Linux, even the touch pad!